# Variable from another file through dict value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Will be better if I explain this situation with a simple example, I have one file with some dictionaries like this example:

file1:

```
dict1 = {"a": "dictA", "b": "dictB"}
dictA = {1: 100, 2:200 }
```

file2:

```
import file1
mydict = file1.dict1["a"]  #will be string "dictA"
print file1.mydict        #here AttributeError:
```

When I tried:

```
print file1.mydict
```

the output is just:

```
dictA
```

Also I tried:

```
import file1
print file1.file1.dict1["a"]      #here AttributeError again:
```

Where I got the AttributeError I would like to print dictA from file1, but obviously python cant find mydict, also I tried this way:

Is there any way to get to the second dictionary?
Thanks

Comment: When you assign `mydict = ...`, you can then access it directly at `mydict`; why add `file1.`?

Comment: Have you tried `print mydict` instead of `print file1.mydict`?

Comment: when I tried "print mydict" it just prints "dictA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Modify file1:

```
dictA = {1: 100, 2:200 }
dict1 = {"a": dictA, "b": dictB}
```

Try:

```
import file1
mydict = file1.dict1["a"]
```

**Method 2**

Do not modify file 1.  Use eval() function to get the value of a variable by its name.

```
mydict = eval('file1.' + file1.dict1["a"])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'file1'

Comment: Method 2 works perfectly with file1 modificate and without modificate, for method1 got that AttributeError. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your first example:

You are working with things you've defined in `file1`, from within `file2`. Thus, when you do `mydict = file1.dict1["a"]`, you get a `mydict` in `file2`, not in `file1`. So you should be able to print it out like this:

```
import file1
mydict = file1.dict1["a"]  #will be string "dictA"
print mydict
```

Note the lack of `file1.` in the print statement there. This happens because `mydict` is created within `file2` and is not written to `file1`.

In your second example:

`file1` doesn't have anything called `file1` defined within it. If you did have such an object within `file1`, which had an attribute called `dict1`, then that call would work without an error.